# Como definir a posição do cursor em um elemento editável?

Tags: javascript, html, posição-do-cursor

Eu tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```html
<pre id="editor" contenteditable="true">
“Always pass on what you have learned.” - Yoda

> {|}

--
X    
</pre>
```

Eu quero que quando alguém clique em um botão eu coloque o cursor no lugar de `{|}`. Esse texto `{|}` realmente existe no meu elemento, eu posso substituí-lo por um elemento html se necessário.

Como posso definir a posição do cursor, para que quando começar a digitar meu texto apareça ali naquela posição?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Td3pV/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você precisa usar os objectos `Range` e `Selection` para obter um intervalo selecionado dentro do elemento:

```js
// marca lugar para posicionar o cursor em `editor`
var marker = '{|}';

// cria intervalo
var range = document.createRange();
var index = editor.innerText ? editor.innerText.indexOf(marker) : editor.textContent.indexOf(marker);
range.setStart(editor.childNodes[0], index);
range.setEnd(editor.childNodes[0], index + marker.length);

// faz seleção
var selection = window.getSelection();
selection.addRange(range);

editor.focus();
```

Fiddle [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/Td3pV/8/).

Comment: Em Linux com Firefox 25.0, nenhuma das soluções coloca o cursor na posição indicada para iniciar a escrita. Podes indicar que navegadores suportam esta solução?

Comment: Alterei o código para usar `textContent` quando `innerText` não estiver disponível e focar no editor. Funciona no Firefox 23 para Windows. Mas, como mencionado por @utluiz, você deve adaptar o código se a div contém outros elementos (adaptando `childNodes[0]`).

Comment: ... também funciona no Firefox 26 para Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Como o Jordão já respondeu, com uma boa resposta por sinal, é possível localizar o texto dentro do editor.

No entanto, usar o `childNodes[0]` não vai funcionar caso haja tags html dentro do editor que englobem o marcador do cursor. Veja um exemplo neste [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Td3pV/7/), cujo HTML é:

```html
<pre id="editor" contenteditable="true">
“Always pass on what you have learned.” - Yoda
<div>
> {|}
</div>

--
X    
</pre>
```

Preparei uma versão usando uma tag HTML com um `id` especial que evita esse problema e ainda permite posicionar o cursor sem precisar de um elemento visual.

O código ficou assim:

```js
function setCursor(node, cursorElement) {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.setStart(cursorElement, 0);
    range.collapse(true);
    if (window.getSelection) {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
        node.focus();
    } else if (document.selection && range.select) {
        range.select();
    }
}

var editor = document.querySelector("#editor");
var button = document.querySelector("button");

button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        setCursor(editor, document.querySelector("#cur"));
    }, 200);
}, false);
```

O marcador é uma tag `span`, como no trecho abaixo:

```html
<pre id="editor" contenteditable="true">
“Always pass on what you have learned.” - Yoda

> <span id="cur"/>

--
X    
</pre>
```

Veja o [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Td3pV/9/).

Comment: Em Linux com Firefox 25.0, nenhuma das soluções coloca o cursor na posição indicada para iniciar a escrita. Podes indicar que navegadores suportam esta solução?

Comment: +1 Sim! Se a `div` em questão tiver outros elementos, `childNodes[0]` deverá ser adaptado.

Comment: @Zuul No firefox precisa de um `node.focus()`. Atualizei a resposta. Havia testado no Chrome e no IE 9. :(

Comment: @utluiz Oi! Estou tendo problemas relacionados a essa pergunta, contudo estou com receio de criar outra. Veja, eu possuo a posição númerica em que o cursor deverá ficar, contudo dentro dessa div editável existem tags como <img> que são emojis e que devem ser considerados caracteres igualmente. Meu código não as considera caracter, veja: https://jsfiddle.net/3uvn0mqv/